# Как центрировать модальное окно по вертикали?

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap

Отображаю модальное окно, но оно отображается сверху.

Как отобразить его по середине?

```
<a id="menuLoginA" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal">Войти</a>

<!-- Login -->
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" id="loginModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Вход на сайт</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Е-майл</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Е-майл">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Пароль</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Пароль">
                    </div>      
                    <div align="right"><a href="/user/forgot">Забыли пароль?</a></div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" id="userEnter" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Вход</button>
                <button type="button" id="userEnter" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Отмена</button>
                <a class="btn btn-success" href="/user/signup" role="button">Регистрация</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: И ещё раз: без кода вопрос не имеет смысла.

Comment: скомбинируйте мой ответ и ответ **Alliswell** может что и получится

Answer (score 2):

На самом деле задача не так проста, как кажется. Необходимо учесть случай, когда размеры окна браузера будут меняться. Самое простое решение - использовать **jQuery** + плагин **fancybox**, там всё это делается автоматически. Тогда вана ссылка-кнопка будет выглядеть так

```
<a id="menuLoginA" href="#loginModal">Войти</a>
```

А в javascript останется дописать

```
$('#menuLoginA').fancybox({padding: 0});
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте следующее (`margin-top` должен быть равен половине `height`):

Если размеры модального окна не известны:

**JS**

```
var modal_height = $('.modal-dialog').height();
$('.modal-dialog').css('margin-top', '-'+modal_height+'px');
```

Если размеры модального окна известны:

**CSS**

```
.modal-dialog {  
    width: 600px;
    height: 450px;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -225px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: А если я не знаю height окна???

Comment: Я не задаю размеры окна по вертикали... Они формируются автоматически

Comment: @sitev_ru, в таком случае, все тоже самое, только этот css задавайте на jQuery.

Comment: @sitev_ru обновил ответ

Answer (score 0):

html

```
<input type="button" id="btn" value="GetSize" />
```

Javascript

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
    alert(window.screen.height);
})
```

как то так.